# Ableton live trial audio not working

Tags: beginner, ableton-live

I am completely noob. Audio in my Ableton is not working while I put the Track inside main pain. Testing audio pieces and side tab is working. I have tested preferences and test option give inside there. None have worked so far.

Pardon me for such a basic question. Please help

Comment: Hi Umesh, welcome to MP&T! I would this question is too broad, would be difficult to answer with the provided information here. Maybe you would have more success following a tutorial on Ableton Live or asking for their support?

Comment: As Tom said, this isn't on topic here - there are far too many things that could cause this. I'd suggest visiting https://forum.ableton.com/ where they discuss all aspects of Ableton software